# How can I make gmaven-plugin groovy code cause maven to exit with a failure?

Tags: gmaven-plugin

I have a pom.xml file with some groovy code that is run by gmaven-plugin.
I would like to detect if a setting is missing and then have maven exit with 'BUILD FAILURE'.
I would prefer to be able to display an error message as well, but I can manually do that so no big deal.
This works but is very ugly (since it makes maven say "Exception: / by zero")

```
testResult = true
if (testResult) {
    println "good keep going"
} else {
    println "bad make maven fail"
    someVal = 1.0 / 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always explicitly throw an exception, e.g.:

```groovy
throw new RuntimeException('build is failing! call the fire brigade!');
```

Comment: Seems better than my idea, assuming that the error actually shows up in the console.